# UTF-8 Headaches Access to mySQL/PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ms-access, utf-8

My mySQL database create shows

```
CREATE DATABASE `foo` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci */
```

The mySQL field collation shows `utf8_unicode_ci`.

The Access export specifies a Code Page of `Unicode (UTF-8)`.

The importing query is

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/foo/Snapshot/tblImages.txt' INTO TABLE `tblImages` CHARACTER SET utf8 FIELDS OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '|' TERMINATED BY ';' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Before drawing the page PHP issues

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

In the `<head>` I have

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

If I open the Access exported txt file in UltraEdit under Windows 7 I see correct accents:

**Plan d’une propriété située dans la première Municipalité (1000 Dauphine corner St. Philip)**

If I query the data in mySQL monitor under Linux I see:

**Plan dâune propriÃ©tÃ© situÃ©e dans la premiÃ¨re MunicipalitÃ© (1000 Dauphine corner St. Philip)**

And when I echo the query output to a browser I see:

**Plan d?une propri?t? situ?e dans la premi?re Municipalit? (1000 Dauphine corner St. Philip)**

If I preface the other queries with:

```
SET NAMES utf8;
```

Then **in Webkit browsers** I see:

[image: utf-8 issue]

What am I missing here?

Comment: make sure the database connection is using utf-8 too

Comment: Issuing these queries:  mysql_query("SET collation_connection = utf8_unicode_ci");  mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8;");  when connecting does ensure this yes?

Comment: Are you sure that the exported txt file is encoded in UTF8? IF not encode it in UTF8 and try importing again. You can also execute  `SET NAMES 'utf8';` before 'importing' the file (this will set 3 session variables to use the appropriate encoding)

Comment: Thanks for the comment - I am sure that Access is set to use UTF-8 and when exported text file is opened in Ultra-Edit that is confirmed.

Comment: if you edit the file using a editor, are you sure the file is properly saved into utf-8 too?

Comment: I don't edit the file I just checked encoding using UltraEdit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was resolved by adding these queries to the connection:

```
mysql_query("SET collation_connection = utf8_unicode_ci");
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8;");
```

And THEN a call to `utf8_encode()` wrapping the output.

The function call ought not be needed given all of the headers and Content-Type settings...?