# UTF-8 in access database

Tags: database, ms-access, utf-8, character-encoding

Im using Access 2013 with PHP and trying to output text from the database but it gives me �������

-The files are saved UTF-8

-meta tag defines the charset

-When I write some text (in Hebrew), the text is displayed correctly.

earlier I managed to make it work, but now I dont know what to do...

Help ?

Tnx !

Comment: Have you had a look at these similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12996926/how-to-set-utf8-on-php-when-connect-to-access-2007-odbc and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8390035/utf-8-headaches-access-to-mysql-php